# Draw absolute arcTo path with canvas android

Tags: java, android, canvas, svg

I have a path data:

```
M50,0A50,50,0,0 1 100,50 L100,85 A15,15,0,0 1 85,100 L50,100 A50,50,0,0 1 50,0z
```

I would to reproduce this path with canvas, so I've made this:

```
        Path p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(50,0);
        p.arcTo(50,50,100,50,0,0,false);
        p.lineTo(100,85);
        p.arcTo(15,15,85,100,0,0,false);
        p.lineTo(50,100);
        p.arcTo(50,50,50,0,0,0,false);
        p.close();
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
```

But this isn't what I would like to create, I'm thinking about an issue with "A" path because documentation said:

> Corresponds to a "absolute arcto" (A) path data command.

So my question is: I'm wrong with `.arcTo` command of canvas?

Comment: try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/t8yB2yXf)

Comment: @pskink Works like a charm! only one question, how to increase size of this path?

Comment: `Path#transform`, btw next time compile those three java files: https://pastebin.com/raw/cpLxgWH7, get the `PathParser.java` from support library and remove both `android` imports

Comment: @pskink You should put answer because it works and it's perfect

Comment: yes i know but... i'm too lazy ;-) for future compile those 3 java sources into a jar and simply run: `java -jar PathParser.jar [optional path data]`

Comment: but honestly i have no idea why it generates those stupid `path.rLineTo(0f, 0f);` - its pointless imho